# How to test for values of child nodes in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML like this:

```
<Product>
 <productCode>ABC</productCode>
 <actionType>NW</actionType>
 <product>
   <productCode>66890</productCode>
   <actionType>NW</actionType>
    <product>
     <productCode>66889</productCode>
     <actionType>NW</actionType>
    </product>
 </product>
</Product>
```

I need to have a xsl choose.
When productCode = 66890 and productCode != 66889

"do something"

when productCode = 66890 or productCode = 66889

"do something"

I tried writing this:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="//product/productCode[contains(.,'66890')] and 
 //product/productCode[not(contains(.,'66889'))]">
 <!--A table will be created -->
 </xsl:when>
<xsl:choose>
```

But this doesnt work. The table gets created.. Ideally it should not since 66889 exists in the xml.

what am i doing wrong?Please help.

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: it worked with the solution below :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little hard for me to tell what you're trying to do, but if I do understand correctly, this should work for *`When productCode = 66890 and productCode != 66889`*...

```xml
//product[.//productCode[contains(.,'66890')] and not(.//productCode[contains(.,'66889')])]
```

Additionally, if you're looking for an exact match I would not use `contains()`. I'd do something like `normalize-space()='66890'`.